# How can i share a variable value between 2 components in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am playing around with angular2. I have created 1 component using angular cli called appmenu.

appmenu.html as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li (click)="menuitem1()">Menu Item 1</li>
  <li>Menu Item 2</li>
  <li>Menu Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

i wish to fetch the value of `testvariable` on app.component.html, but i dont know what should i do in my `app.component.ts`

`appmenu.ts as follows`

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  providers: [AppMenuService], // GIVING ERROR HERE
  selector: 'app-appmenu',
  templateUrl: './appmenu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./appmenu.component.css']
})
export class AppmenuComponent implements OnInit {
public testvariable = "1st";
public data: any;
 // constructor(private sharedData: AppMenuService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   // this.data = this.sharedData.data;
   // console.log(this.data);
  }

  menuitem1(){
    console.log("Menu item 1 clicked");
  }

}
```

`appmenu.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppMenuService{
public data: any;
    constructor() {
        this.data = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit.';
    }
}
```

Getting error on `appmenu.component.ts` here -> `providers: [AppMenuService]` , it says cannot find name AppMenuService

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @ViewChild annotation for this in your parent component:

```
@ViewChild(AppmenuComponent) appComponent: AppmenuComponent;
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: he wants to use the variable inside the parent component

Answer (score 0):

If you want to statically share a variable between two components you can declare this variable in some service and use this variable by injecting this service. E.g.

```
// shared-data.service.ts

export class SharedDataService {
    public data: any;
    constructor() {
        this.data = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit.';
    }
}

// app.component.ts

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public data: any;

    constructor(private sharedData: SharedDataService) { }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.data = this.sharedData.data;
    }
}

// app-menu/app-menu.component.ts

@Component({ ... })
export class AppMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    public data: any;

    constructor(private sharedData: SharedDataService) { }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.data = this.sharedData.data;
    }
}
```

But commonly when you need to shared some data between parent and child components you need to use `@Input` and `@Output`. `@Input` allows you to pass data directly to the child component/directive. `@Output` allows you to listen events of child component. Learn more [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#sts=Pass%20data%20from%20parent%20to%20child%20with%20input%20binding).

E.g.

```
// app.component.ts

@Component({
    template: `
        <app-menu
            [someData]="dataForChild"
            (menuClick)="handleMenuClick($event)">
        </app-menu>
    `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public dataForChild: any;

    constructor() { }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.dataForChild = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit.'
    }

    public handleMenuClick(itemIndex) {
        console.log(itemIndex);
    }
}

// app-menu/app-menu.component.ts

@Component({
    selector: 'app-menu',
    template: `
        <ul>
            <li (click)="transferMenuClick(1)">Menu item 1</li>
            <li (click)="transferMenuClick(2)">Menu item 2</li>
            <li (click)="transferMenuClick(3)">Menu item 3</li>
        </ul>
    `
})
export class AppMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output('menuClick')
    public menuClick: EventEmitter<number>;

    @Input('someData')
    public someData: any;

    constructor(private sharedData: SharedDataService) {
        this.menuClick = new EventEmitter<number>;
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.someData);
    }

    public transferMenuClick(itemIndex) {
        this.menuClick.emit(itemIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am going to try both the ways, for the 1st one i created a service called `appmenu.service.ts` , updated above and called it in `appmenu.component.ts` , getting error , dont know whats wrong that i am doing

Comment: But i was looking for something else, like when i clicked a menu item on appmenu.ts it calls a function , i want to fetch the value from here on app.ts , is your 2nd solution capable to provide this solution ?

Comment: @user2828442 yes, it provides this solution. If you look at my example - you'll see that the click on menu item is handled by `AppMenuComponent.transferMenuClick` method. This method simply emits index of clicked menu item. After that, index is passed to `AppComponent.handleMenuClick` method and this method simply logs menu-item index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146063/discussion-between-user2828442-and-embarq).